# About how to divide a list relatively evenly

Tags: java, algorithm, kotlin

I have a list. I need to divide it into 4 groups, and the sum of each group is relatively average. The list can be sorted or not.

Give an example: list(1,1,4,2,2,3,5,6) -> Divide into (1,1,4), (2,2,3), (5), (6).

Thanks in advance here, I know this requires some algorithmic ability.

Comment: Please post the code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I don't have any ideas to solve the problem. Do I need to solve it by greedy and seeking peace?

Comment: A greedy algorithm would help as the choice is to know whether to add a number to the current sub list or to start a new sub list

Comment: Why is this tagged both `java` and `kotlin`?

Comment: Because I need to use Java or Kotlin to achieve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three things to play with here.
a set of numbers, no of segments  and the average of each segment.

If two of these are set, the third is automatically set.
In your case, your set of numbers is pre-defined and the no of segments is predefined - hence the average is also pre-defined.

You need to find this average and then run through the numbers. If the segments are required to be contiguous as in your example, this is the only way to do this.

If the elements in the segment can be non contiguous, then there are a lot more possibilities and your chances of getting to an `even` distribution is also better. You can keep a track of the four segments and add to whatever segment seems to be furthest away from it's target average. This is a greedy way to do this.

Keep in mind that your array could be horribly skewed.
Say the average is 6 and your array looks like
`{ 24 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0}` 
The ONLY distribution possible here would be
`{24} ,{ 0 } , {0 , 0 ,0 },{0 , 0 ,0 }`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I understand what you mean. But I still can't write any code.

Comment: Try this - maintain four empty lists. Calculate the `average` and then run through your original list. While doing this, for each element you have to choose which bucket you should be adding it to. One way to choose that would be to see which bucket is the furthest away from the average and add it to that. There could be other more effective ways.

Comment: The method chosen is that the average of the four lists is the largest compared to the average of the original list?

Comment: The sublist for which the sum of it's elements (the ones already added) is the furthest away from the average of the original list.

Comment: ok Thanks a lot , i will try it. thanks agine!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps find the average of each group like so: (1+1+4+2+2+3+5+6)/4=6 and keep track of the total sum of each group. If it is in a certain [allowable] range, say 1 or 2, then proceed to the next list.